# Filter data using multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, filter

The data in my table looks like this

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
1   |   101     | 10    |   123
2   |   102     | 10    |   123
3   |   103     | 10    |   123
4   |   104     | 10    |   012
5   |   105     | 20    |   789
6   |   106     | 20    |   789
7   |   107     | 30    |   003
```

I have a field for the user. Where the user can choose the PID they want to show.
I need to be able to filter the PID and the TID linked to the BID.

I mean for example when I have 5 BID for TID 123 I would like all of those to show.

And when the user enters 10 on the PID it will only show:

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
1   |   101     | 10    |   123
2   |   102     | 10    |   123
3   |   103     | 10    |   123
```

Update:

I added another field for the user to select the TID. This is my query

```
SELECT 
BID, 
TID,
PID

FROM 
Table1

WHERE 
PID = "1" AND
TID = "123"
```

If I use 'AND' and the user only enters 1 on the PID and doesn't touch the TID, there's no output just like this

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
```

If the user specifies the correct TID and enters for example 1 on the PID and 123 on the TID the output will be: THIS IS THE CORRECT OUTPUT

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
1   |   101     | 10    |   123
2   |   102     | 10    |   123
3   |   103     | 10    |   123
```

Now if the user enters 2 on the PID and leaves 123 on the TID the output will be like this

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
```

Basically, the user have to fill the 2 fields for it to have the correct output.

My question is, how can I filter it correctly? Where when the user enters the PID and doesn't specify the TID it will still have the correct output.

If you notice on the data

```
ID  |   BID     | PID   |   TID
4   |   104     | 10    |   012
```

This record have the same PID with ID's 1,2 and 3 but different in TID. I only need to return the values for the BID specified for the specific TID's like with the TID (123) I need to return those items only.

I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough for some of you guys, but I hope that having more description will make you guys atleast understand my problem. Thank You.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If the chooses PID 10, why is it only showing TID = 123?

Comment: @Barmar I added more description. Is that better?

Comment: If the user enters just one column, you just filter that one column. If he enters two column, you filter both columns with `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TID=123
```

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Can you show your current mysql query for that table with column names and we can modify it more clearly for you, but it would be something like this:

```
BID MySQL Query: "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TID = 123"
PID MySQL Query: "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PID = 10"
```

To dynamically filter you would replace the 123 and 10 with values from the user.  We need to know what type of server side code you're using as well.  PHP I take it?  Post sample code of that as well.

Comment: +1 looks right to me, so lets do something about that "don't have enough reputation" :D

Comment: @madamission i added the query i'm using and added more description. is that better?